# Scalability of multi-threaded vector sum

Tags: c++, multithreading, scalability

Here is a piece of C++11 code for a multi-threaded vector sum.

```
#include <thread>

template<typename ITER>
void sum_partial(ITER a, ITER b, double & result) {
  result = std::accumulate(a, b, 0.0);
}

template<typename ITER>
double sum(ITER begin, ITER end, unsigned int nb_threads) {
  size_t len = std::distance(begin, end);
  size_t size = len/nb_threads;

  std::vector<std::thread> thr(nb_threads-1);
  std::vector<double> r(nb_threads);
  size_t be = 0;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads-1; i++) {
    size_t en = be + size;
    thr[i] = std::thread(sum_partial<ITER>, begin + be, begin + en, std::ref(r[i]));
    be = en;
  }
  sum_partial(begin + be, begin + len, r[nb_threads-1]);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < nb_threads-1; i++)
    thr[i].join();
  return std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), 0.0);
}
```

The typical use will be `sum(x.begin(), x.end(), n)` with `x` a vector of doubles.

Here is a graph displaying the computation time as a function of the number of threads (average time for summing 10⁷ values, on a 8 cores computer with nothing else running -- I tried on a 32 cores computer, the behaviour is very similar).

[image]

Why is the scalability so poor? Can it be improved?

My (very limited) understanding is that to have good scalability, threads should avoid to write in the same cache line. Here all threads write in `r` once, at the very end of their computation, I wouldn't expect it to be the limiting factor. Is it a memory bandwidth problem?

Comment: needs units on y axis.

Comment: @UKMonkey it's in seconds but I don't think it matters...

Comment: well, if it takes [Milliseconds to create thread: 0.015625](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274217/how-long-does-thread-creation-and-termination-take-under-windows) It looks like thread creation could be your bottleneck - if your units are wrong

Comment: Good point, but code using a thread pool (through the TBB library) displays a similar behaviour.

Comment: That would've been the better code to post as it has less variables ;)

Comment: The test can (and should) be adjust to prepare the threads ahead (and start calculation with signal), and even allow vectorization, but he'll still see low scalability due to cache stalls.

Comment: @UKMonkey I chose to post the most readable code... Besides, if takes 0.015 milliseconds to create one threads, then to create 6 threads it takes 0.09 milliseconds, which is negligible as compared to a total run time of 4 milliseconds.

Comment: @Non-maskableInterrupt I trust the standard library to allow vectorization in `std::accumulate`, am I wrong? (anyway that’s a totally different question)

Comment: @Elvis which is why units matter.

Comment: `std::accumulate` is template, such vectoization is controlled by compiler optimzation option. You may also want to enable prefetch (updated answer)

Comment: @Elvis Yes, you are wrong. `std::accumulate` is defined as a left fold, and vectorization would break this because floating point addition [is not associative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371857/is-floating-point-addition-and-multiplication-associative#10371890). (Depending on the fp strictness settings, the library/compiler might do it anyway, though.) I would definitely argue against using `std::accumulate` for best performance.

Comment: @Non-maskableInterrupt Nothing prevents a library from having optimized specializations of `accumulate` e.g. for a pointer or vector range of "normal" arithmetic type. In fact, the algorithm implementations in the standard are for exposition only. UPDATE: Err, well, I'm contradicting myself a bit here. Should say provided the result is the same, which in the fp case it's not. A vectorized integer accumulate would be fine, however.

Comment: @ArneVogel ok, thanks, this is very informative

Answer (score 4):

`accumulate` has low utilitation on cpu arithmetic units, but cache and memory throughput will most likely be the bottleneck, especially for 10^7 double, or 10 million double = 80MB data, which is way more than your CPU cache size.

---

To overcome the cache and memory throughput bottleneck, you might want to [enable prefetch](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html) with `-fprefetch-loop-arrays`, or even manually do some assembly.